# How to reenter Vim after :! bash?

Tags: bash, vim, command-line

I'm slowing getting to know Vim and Bash shell scripting and am running into this issue:

When I'm running MacVim, I sometimes want to use the command line to compile whatever it is I'm working on (in this case a small Java program). So I type `:! bash` and compile whatever it is that I need and test it. Then when I want to go back to the program I was editing I type `vim MyProgram.java` and get all kinds of messyness in my Vim session like `[8;1H~ [9:1H~ [10:1H~ ... etc.`

What am I doing wrong here? Can I not jump back into Vim once I've started running the shell inside of it?

Are there better ways of compiling and running your current file?

(I'm using MacVim 7.2 and Bash 3.2.48 on OSX 10.6.2.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. Use `exit` to quit the bash shell and return to vim.
2. Within vim, use `:set makeprg=name_of_your_make_program` to automatically compile from within vim with the `:make` command.  As a bonus, if it's a toolset that vim recognizes, vim will parse the compiler's output, show you the errors, and allow you to jump to each of them so you can fix them.  See the commands `:cl`, `:cc`, `:cn`, and `:cp` for starters.

Comment: It's helpful to :map a couple of function keys to the :cn and :cp commands.  Jumping back and forth is a lot faster that way.

Answer (score 6):

just type:

```
exit
```

This will exit the `bash` sub-process and return to vim. It would be better to use something like GNU Screen to maintain a Vim and Bash session simultaneously (and it's easier to switch than `:!bash`...`exit`

Comment: 2 1/2 years later, tmux > screen.

Comment: @Adam: Really? It seems to be focusing on being a lightweight alternative (and it doesn't have all of screen's features). Any particularly compelling reason to switch?

Comment: More a personal preference, I think.  There's some info at http://tmux.sourceforge.net/, and a (very brief) comparison at http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/Screen_vs_tmux (Bonus: now I know about wikivs!)

Answer (score 4):

You must exit the bash shell. This can be done by the `exit` command, or more simply by pressing <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd> at the prompt.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are right.

I just want to mention that you can use

```
:sh
```

instead of

```
:!bash
```

See `:help sh`.

This way vim knows you are running a shell instead of just some command (which happens to be bash).

Answer (score 1):

Try typing `exit` or ctrl-d from within the bash shell.  That will take you back into vim.  Bash is running "inside" vim, so if you try and run vim again, you're running vim inside bash inside vim and hence the errors.

Answer (score 0):

If your in Mac OS, you'll probably have to type `fg` to return back to vim after executing a bash command. Others didn't work for me.

Comment: Not in this case. There are two ways of using interactive shell from “inside” vim: start a new one as a child process (as TS did) or suspend vim (which should get you into the *parent* shell, if vim was launched from the shell, of course). `exit` is for the first case, `fg` is for the second.